# How to root Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300?

Tags: rooting, root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-3, twrp

I'm using *Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300* with Android version 4.3. For some reasons I need to install TWRP, which requires root.

My question is **How to root my device**.

I've used ODIN, Kingroot, and Kingo Root. But none of them could root my device.

I need your help to root this device successfully.

Comment: Have you enabled "OEM unlock" in developer options?

Comment: https://autoroot.chainfire.eu

Comment: Flash UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.46.zip with built-in stock recovery. You don't need Odin or to flash some ROM.

Comment: @Robert I couldn't find OEM Unlock in developers menu.